# Pasar datos de un table view a un view controller Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Estoy tratando de pasar datos ya guardados en un Core Data desde un `UITableView` a un *view controller*. El código me compila sin error pero cuando ejecuto no me presenta en el `UILabel` la información que tendría que mandar.

Este es el código del *table view*:

```
import UIKit

class CostumerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var costumerArray:[Costumer] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.fetchData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return costumerArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let name = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = name.costumerName!
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let costumerDelete = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(costumerDelete)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
            do {
                costumerArray = try context.fetch(Costumer.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "costumerDetailViewController") as! costumerDetailViewController
        let n = costumerArray[indexPath.row]
        let Cn = n.costumerName!
        DvC.getCostumerName = Cn
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
    }

    func fetchData() {
        // se crea el context
        let  context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {  // se hace el request del array
            costumerArray = try context.fetch(Costumer.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Y este el del *view controller*:

```
import UIKit

class costumerDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var getCostumerName = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelName.text! = getCostumerName
    }
}
```

Veo que no me da error en ningún lado, no veo qué está pasando.

Comment: Pregunta. Cuando asignas `DvC.getCostumerName = Cn`, ¿la variable `Cn` tiene el valor correcto? Y a propósito, en Swift las variables comienzan con una minúscula, y ¡¡¡¿por qué el "get" en el nombre de la propiedad?!!!

Comment: la variable `Cn` tiene como valor `n.costumerName` que es parte del entity

Comment: Sí... la pregunta es si en ejecución tiene el valor correcto... Si pones un _breakpoint_ en esa línea, ¿tiene el valor?

Comment: en ejecución no da ningún valor